# Wordpress Custom Menu Widget Style

Tags: menus, widgets, columns

I am wondering if anyone knows the best method for splitting 1 custom menu widget (located in my sites footer) in to 2 columns. There are a total of 8 links, so I would like it to be split in to 2 columns of 4 links. Not sure if there is a function for this or is there some CSS to achieve this? The HTML markup from the widget looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li id="menu-item-133" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-6 current_page_item menu-item-133">
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

repeat that structure 7 more times for the line items code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purely with CSS you could set a width for menu items, float them and then set the UL to twice that:

```
footer ul {
    width: 200px;
}
footer .menu-item {
    float: left;
    width: 100px
}
```

(I don't know what elements you are using to designate your footer, you'll need to update that to match your structure.)

Comment: Something so simple, figured it would require a custom hook or function (not sure why).. thank you for you help!

Answer (score 1):

You can assign individual CSS classes to the menu items from a custom navigation menu, in `http://example.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php`.

So, the first 4 links would have a `widget-left-column` class, and the others `widget-right-column`.
So you'll be able to do your CSS stuff to split the widget in two columns <sup>(strict CSS questions are off-topic in WordPress StackExchange)</sup>.

#### Assigning CSS classes to individual custom navigation menu items

Instead of repeating the same screenshots, I'll reproduce here [@JeremyJared's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45229/12615) to a similar Question:

> **First, go to the screen options and select the css checkbox:**
>
> [image: enable navigation menu classes]
>
> **Next, open the menu item and give it a class. In my example it would have the class .home-page:**
>
> [image: navigation menu class]

---

*Note that for assigning more than one class, you have to use a whitespace to separate them.*
[image: navigation menus multiple classes]
*Which results in the following Html:*
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Simpler is

```
footer .menu-item {
   width:50%;
   float: left;
 }
```